# How can I set scroll tab layout to my JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtabbedpane

I have a `JTabbedPane`. I drag it from the palette and paste it in my form. I put 5 panel on it. It is OK but when I put 6, panel on it it does not seen on the form because the place is not enough width. I put this code

`tab_group.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);`

But doesn't affect my code. How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it will help.

```
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    add(pane);
```

add Jscrollpane to panel. problem solve

Comment: panel is the 6. panel? and add(pane) to where?

Comment: JScrollPane(panel -> this panel is My JTabbedPane ? or my last panel

Comment: panel contain your 5 tabbedpane and 6th panel.  like this **panel.add(jtappedPane1); panel.add(jtappedPane2); .... panel.add(6thpanel); JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
frame.add(pane);**

Comment: When I do that it doesnt work properly, the form is all empty

Comment: I add print screen I put Jtabbedpane just one and in it I put 6 panel. I want to show scroll on jtabbedpane